# Question title goes to the second line in the middle of a word

Tags: bug, status-completed

On [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57401/8632), I have noticed that the next line of the question title begins in the middle of the word, depending on how wind I have my screen width.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This happens on Meta too. I'm seeing this on Safari 12.0.1 on macOS 10.14.1.

I expect that the title will spill over to the second line with whole words, not in the middle of the word. So for instance, I would expect:

`Is there a term for the belief
that what is popular in 
society defines what is moral?`

Rather than

`Is there a term for the belief th
at what is popular in society d
efines what is moral?`

Can this bug be fixed so that titles are more readable? I'd hate for meaning to be misunderstood if line breaks happen in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This network-wide issue was resolved here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318833/235711

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was an issue only in the edit mode, but it also appears in the display mode as your example illustrates.

I checked the following long titles and they appeared correct when displayed for reading. However, as Eliran note,d when one resizes the window they can be inaccurately displayed.

- [What Are Some Recurring Questions/Themes That Are Explored or Argued for in Renaissance Philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57301/29944)
- [What is the difference between a prediction and an expression of intention according to Anscombe?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/38804/29944)

I agree that it would be nice to have the titles displayed better.

Comment: For me they aren't. Did you check if they are still displayed correctly when you resize your window?

Comment: @Eliran You're right. When I resized the window there was a place where the title did not display correctly even on these two examples. So this bug is a problem more generally than I thought.